# Restrict access to entire website except the homepage using .htacess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, wordpress

I have just put a website live, but I need to restrict access to everything except the homepage for users outside of my IP address.

I would like to do this using .htaccess.

So far I have come up with this but it doesn't work:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1

<Files /index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

The file that I want to make viewable to the world is located here:

/var/www/html/mysite/web/wp-content/themes/ubergrid/index.php.

The .htacess file is located here:

/var/www/html/mysite/web/

Wordpress re-writes everything to /index.php which complicates matters.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Allow from all" should provide a hint.

Answer (score 0):

First, your solution probably won't do what you want, because you haven't allowed for image, CSS, or Javascript files.

Since as you say Wordpress rewrites everything to /index.php, it seems that your choices are either to intercept that rewriting before it takes place, or find a way to work within Wordpress to restrict access.  The second choice seems more likely to succeed.  I see there's a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/restricted-site-access/) that claims to do it, and it has a [FAQ](https://wordpress.org/plugins/restricted-site-access/faq/) on how to restrict access to just part of the site.